# firebase storage xmlhttprequest error in MV3 chrome service worker

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, firebase-storage, service-worker

I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined` when I try to run this code below

```
    let resUrl = await fetch(request.fileDataUrl);
    let blob = await resUrl.blob()
    let uploadRes = uploadBytes(storageRef, blob) //<<======the error is from tis line
```

I have tried using this [xhr-shim polyfills](https://github.com/apple502j/xhr-shim#readme) but still getting same error. I think I may not be using it properly since they didn't really state how to use it in their documentation.

but what I did was just to install and import the package.

please does anyone know to I can resolve this problem?

I am running `firebase@9.17.1`

Comment: A workaround is to do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) as it has a native XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: alright, will try this out. but to have access to the firebase methods, do I need to reinitialize firebase in the `offscreen.js` file again since I already did that in `service-worker.js` and like we know, they run on different environment?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you should use it only there, not inside the background script.

Comment: I am handling authentication in using firebase auth in my background. Will it be possible to move everything firebase related to the offscreen file instead?

updated:
I doubt that will be possible cause according to the doc link you shared, it's only `chrome.runtime`  API that's currently available in the offscreen environment. meanwhile authentication with firebase in mv3 currently can only be done with `chrome.identity`